# How does R understand a multi level model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I'm new to MLM both in R and in general. I have a dataset of Building permits for a couple of cities and I have created a variable counting the number of parcels with a permit. Now, I want to perform a MLM to see if there is a census tract (a geographic level) effect going on. Here's where I hit a problem. When writing this line:

lmer(PERMITS ~ 1 + howeownership + (1 | CITY), data = dt2, REML = FALSE)
Do I need to also include census tract variable? If not, how would R know that my levels are CITY>>CT>>PERMITS (which is really the outcome)?

P.S. Home ownership is a variable in the census tracts. It is defined as the proportion of poeple being home owners in each tract.

Comment: Can you share the data?

Comment: Is this a programming question? Search for nested random effects.

Answer (score 1):

For multilevel models, which usually model longitudinal/hierarchical structures, we still need to have a design matrix in order to fit the model (either by MLE, RMLE or GLS).

Looking at your code, the design matrix build by the formula you pass onto `lmer` will not contain any information about `CT` apparently. The formula should be something like:

```r
lmer(PERMITS ~ 1 + howeownership + (1 |CT/CITY), data = dt2, REML = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't think of that. Is this code conceptually the same as lmer(PERMITS ~ 1 + howeownership + (1 |CITY) + (1 |CT), data = dt2, REML = FALSE)?

Comment: Nope, those are non nested groups. To picture this, think of the hierarchical structure of states, within a county, within a city as compared to counties that have schools that have teachers when a teacher can teach in multiple schools, and then has to be modelled in a non nested manner, since a teacher can teach in many schools.

Comment: @Sani, those two formulations can produce the same output, however, if you have coded your data correctly. See https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#nested-or-crossed for more information.